# Is it normal that using OBS with the Skype NDI integration is unusable on mid-2015 Macbook Pro?

Tags: youtube, obs

Experimenting with OBS...

I can easily live stream a 5 Mbits stream to YouTube at faster.

As soon as I add a split screen guest via the Skype NDI integration, the stream becomes unusable.

Is it normal I can’t run both OBS and Skype a mid-2015 MacBook Pro?

My Internet connection is a 120/20 and I am wired using Gigabit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Skype is decoding and re-encoding the video stream at that point.  If so, then yes, that's probably entirely normal.  You have two MPEG encoders running at the same time.  My 2017 MBP (i7) struggles to do that with Zoom.

Comment: My 2018 Macbook pro struggles with most OBS-related things. It's pretty processor intensive